# Bootstrap tabs mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Hello everyone I'm trying to modify the bootstrap tabs plugin, to become a tabbed menu, so that instead of click event, it reacted on mouseover/mouseout events. So far I've made it open the tab-pane on mouseover and close on mouseout, but the problem is that on mouseout tab-panes close before the user can choose anything at tab-pane. I need to make tab-panes not to hide if the mouse is over them and only is the mouse has left them.

Here is the jQuery code I've ended up with

```
    (function ($) {
    $('.nav-tabs a').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(e){
        if(e.type == 'mouseover'){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).tab('show');
        }else{
            if($('.tab-pane').hasClass('active')){
                $(this).parent('li').removeClass('active');
                $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
            }
        }
      });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
   $('.nav-tabs a').bind('mouseover', function(e){
        $(this).click();
 });
```

[**Working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2377/)

**Update**

```
  $('.nav-tabs a').bind('mouseover', function(e){
     $('.tab-content').show();
        $(this).click();
  });
  $('.nav-tabs').bind('mouseout', function(e){
     $('.nav-tabs li').removeClass('active');
     $('.tab-content').hide();
  });
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xFW8t/2378/)

Comment: Yes, It will work but the problem of OP won't be solved.

Comment: Manoj, thx for your reply, but the problem is that I need the tabs to become inactive on mouseout (i.e. - the active class is removed from .nav-tabs and .tab-pane ) if mouse goes out of .tab-pane and .nav-tabs, but if mouse is over .tab-pane I need everything to stay active, unless the mouse leaves

Comment: You do not quite understand what i mean - here is the example of what i need ( please see the tabbed menu at this site ) - http://laptop.ru/catalog/noutbuki_planshety/notebooks/